# Метод equals не работает во всех циклах do, кроме последнего

Tags: java

```
public static void userRegistration() {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    User user = new User();
    System.out.println("Зарегистрируйте пользователя");
    System.out.println("Введите фамилию");
    user.setLastName(in.nextLine());
    System.out.println("Введите имя");
    user.setFirstName(in.nextLine());
    System.out.println("Введите отчество");
    user.setSurName(in.nextLine());
    System.out.println("Введите номер телефона");
    while (!user.setPhoneNumber(in.nextLine())) ;
    boolean notunique;
    
    do {
        notunique = false;
        System.out.println("Введите e-mail");
        for (User emailCheck : users) {
            while (!user.setEmail(in.nextLine())) ;
            if (emailCheck.equals(user)) {
                System.out.println("Такой e-mail уже существует, введите другой");
                notunique = true;
            }
        }
    }
    while (notunique);

    do {
        notunique = false;
        System.out.println("Введите логин");
        user.setLogin(in.nextLine());
        for (User loginCheck : users) {
            if (loginCheck.equals(user)) {
                System.out.println("Такой логин уже существует, введите другой");
                notunique = true;
            }
        }
    }
    while (notunique);

    System.out.println("Введите пароль");
    user.setPassword(in.nextLine());
    user.setUserType("guest");
    users.add(user);
    System.out.println("Пользователь добавлен");
}
```

Добавление нового пользователя в `ArrayList`.
Циклами `do` проверяется `e-mail` и логин на уникальность при помощи метода `equals`.
Если проверка уникальности только одна (один цикл `do`), все работает (выдает сообщение о существовании такого же логина или `e-mail`, если он уже есть в списке, просит ввести заново). Если две или больше, то выполняется только последний.

Полазил по другим темам и видеоурокам на ютюбе, поэкспериментировал с переопределением методов `equals()` и `hashCode()` - результат пока тот же. Причем, если делаю всё не через сеттеры, а объявляя переменные перед циклом `do`, то при таком же подходе все работает. Но задание требует делать всё через сеттеры, что бы параллельно еще проверялось соответствие вводимых значений регулярным выражениям в классе User.
Подскажите, почему не выполняются проверки во всех циклах?

Comment: Применять `equals()` на весь объект для выявления не уникальности только одного поля - не лучшая идея, при том, что вы сначала делаете это для одного поля (`email`), а потом совершенно для другого (`login`). Сделайте геттеры в классе `User`, тогда проверка на уникальность может выглядеть как `checkEmail.getEmail().equals(user.getEmail())` в первом цикле и как `checkLogin.getLogin().equals(user.getLogin())` во втором соответственно.

Comment: Имеет смысл завести множества емайлов и логинов `Set<String> emails, logins`, чтобы ускорить и упростить проверку дубликатов без лишних вложенных циклов.

Comment: Зачем вы для каждого _существующего_ пользователя требуете ввода нового емайла для нового пользователя в цикле `while (!user.setEmail(in.nextLine()));`?  Также стоило показать реализацию метода `equals` в классе `User`

Comment: @Byb Ваше предложение по проверке уникальности полностью решило вопрос. Спасибо вам! Нет репутации, что б отметить ваш комментарий, как решение.